# InputFile and TextFieldParser to parse csv

Tags: c#, csv, textfieldparser, blazorinputfile

I can parse a CSV file by using the file path and TextFieldParser.
Now I'm trying to parse a CSV file received from InputFile component.
Here is what I tried:

```cs
var stream = e.File.OpenReadStream();
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
stream.Close();

using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(memoryStream))
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters(";", ",");

    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        //Do something here
    }
}
```

But when I run that, it does not enter the using block and never go further.
What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use try-catch block for see Exceptions and error details.